# Xcode firestore crashing

Tags: xcode, google-cloud-firestore, crash

I have an app that has been recently released on the App Store, however since launch anyone who has tried to use the app crashes whenever they try to do the following action, it worked completely fine all through out testing so am not sure what the problem is?

```
func addSubscriptionData(name: String, price: Double, category: Category, notes: String, theme: String, dateSignedUp: String, billingPeriod: Int, reminder: Bool, daysBefore: Int) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("users").document(preferences.docId).collection("subscriptions").addDocument(data: ["name": name, "price": price, "category": category.rawValue, "notes": notes, "theme": theme, "dateSignedUp": dateSignedUp, "billingPeriod": billingPeriod, "reminder": reminder, "daysBefore": daysBefore]) { error in
        if error == nil {
            self.getSubscriptions()
        }
        else{
            print("Can't add subscription to database")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much
Cian

A crash log:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at the crash logs either in Xcode's organizer or in Crashlytics if you have it set up, that will give more insights on the root cause.

Comment: Hi. I have some crash logs but I am struggling to find any information online on how to interpret them? @VadimBelyaev I have attatched one of the crash logs